# TypeError: Cannot read property 'markForCheck' of undefined Angular6 Impure Pipe Testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6

I am trying to test an impure pipe using jasmine. The pipe works fine on ng serve and does its intended job of animating text.

When I am creating an instance of it in my test cases and trying to get the tranform method run I get error.

> NaturalTypePipe > transforms "abc" to "abc"
>   TypeError:
>
> Cannot read property 'markForCheck' of undefined
>       at 
>       NaturalType../src/app/shared/pipes/natural-type.pipe.ts.NaturalType.typeNextCharacter

My test case file is below:-

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { NaturalType } from './natural-type.pipe';

describe('NaturalTypePipe', () => {
    let changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef;
    let ngZone: NgZone;
    let pipe: NaturalType;

    beforeEach(() => {
        pipe = new NaturalType(changeDetector, ngZone);  
    });

    it('should create an instance of natural pipe', () => {
        expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('transforms "abc" to "abc"', () => {
        expect(pipe.transform('abc')).toBe('abc');
    });
});
```

My pipe code is as follows:-

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

/*
 * Animating text as if it was being typed by a user
*/

@Pipe({name: 'naturalType', pure: false})
export class NaturalType implements PipeTransform {
   private typed: string = '';
   private target: string = '';
   private currentIndex: number = -1;
   private timeoutHandle: number = -1;

   constructor( private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef, private ngZone: NgZone ) { }

   transform(value: string, mintypingSpeed: number = 30): any {
      if (this.target !== value) {
       clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
       this.typed = '';
       this.currentIndex = -1;
       this.target = value;
       this.typeNextCharacter(mintypingSpeed);
      }
      return this.typed;
   }
   
   private typeNextCharacter(mintypingSpeed: number) {
    this.currentIndex++;
    this.typed = this.target.substr(0, this.currentIndex);
    this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
    if (this.typed !== this.target) {
      const time = Math.round(Math.random() * 70) + mintypingSpeed;
      this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.timeoutHandle = <any> setTimeout(()=> {
          this.ngZone.run(() => this.typeNextCharacter(mintypingSpeed));
        },time);
      });  
    }
   }
}
```

My initial thought was this may be due to private constructor variables and private typeNextCharacter method in pipe file and I tried a few things but was not successful.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The `changeDetector` variable is never being initialized. So, the line:

```
pipe = new NaturalType(changeDetector, ngZone);
```

in the beforeEach block is creating a new `NaturalType` with an undefined `changeDetector`.

Comment: I tried to look into how can I initialize that but was unsuccessful. Can you provide any example ? I tried to look in the page https://angular.io/guide/testing and tried few other things. It would be great if you can rewrite my pipe test case file and post as an answer.  Thanks  in advance !!!